# Union and intersection of inverse of function

Tags: general-topology

I've seen a problem and struggling with its solution of 10(C), the → part.

https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-19-the-product-topology/problem-10-solution/

I don't understand why we can have $g^{-1}$ open known $U$  is the union of finite intersections of some subbasis elements $S=f^{−1}_{β}(U_β)$, where each $U_β$ is open in $X$.

Is that true $f^{-1}(A∪B)=f^{-1}(A)∪f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}(A∩B)=f^{-1}(A)∩f^{-1}(B)$? I know the union equation is true and intersect equation is not true for functions, how about inverse of functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in f^{-1}(A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\cap B\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\land f(x)\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\land x\in f^{-1}(B)\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$

So $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$

$x\in f^{-1}(A\cup B)\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\cup B\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in A\lor f(x)\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\lor x\in f^{-1}(B)\Leftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$

So $f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$

Comment: For the general result of $\cap_{i\in I}A_i$ you just have to play with $f(x)\in A_i\;\forall\,i\in I$

Comment: For the general result of $\cup_{i\in I}A_i$ you just have to play with $\exists\,i_0\in I:f(x)\in A_{i_0}$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful! Does the properties of f matter here, like injection or surjection?

Comment: Not at all. This is true for all functions.